# Python and Django version issue

Tags: python, django

I was recomended to create a web site with Python - Django framework (instead of php).
In its documentation, Django says that it is not compatible with Python version higher than 2.7.
On Python download page the lowest version available is 2.73.
Any advice ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Django 1.4 and the upcoming 1.5 will work fine with Python 2.7.3.

When Django says Python 2.7, it means 2.7.X. You can use any release of Python 2.7, including 2.7.3.

From the [Django 1.5 faq](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/faq/install/#what-are-django-s-prerequisites):

> Django requires Python, specifically Python 2.6.5 - 2.7.x. No other Python libraries are required for basic Django usage. Django 1.5 also has experimental support for Python 3.2.3 and above.